# Cross Compiling Samba 4.0.5 i686 to MIPS

Tags: linux, preprocessor

I've been assigned to cross compile samba 4.0.5 from i686 to MIPS in order to port it on board later. I'm compiling in ubuntu 13.04 .

The error I get is:

```
lib/sysquotas_4A.c: In function ‘sys_get_vfs_quota’:
lib/sysquotas_4A.c:107:10: error: ‘struct dqblk’ has no member named ‘dqb_curblocks’
lib/sysquotas_4A.c:124:10: error: ‘struct dqblk’ has no member named ‘dqb_curblocks’
lib/sysquotas_4A.c:170:29: error: ‘struct dqblk’ has no member named ‘dqb_curblocks’
The following command failed:
cc -fno-builtin -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT 
-D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -I. 
-I/home/constantine/software_forge/2013/5_month/samba/samba-4.0.5/source3 
-I/home/constantine/software_forge/2013/5_month/samba/samba-4.0.5/source3/../lib/popt 
-I/home/constantine/software_forge/2013/5_month/samba/samba-4.0.5/source3/../lib/iniparser/src 
-Iinclude/autoconf -Iautoconf -Iautoconf/source3 -Iinclude -I./include  
-I. -I. -I./../lib/replace -I./../lib/tevent -I../lib/ccan/.. -I./librpc -I./.. 
-I./../lib/tdb_compat -I./../lib/talloc -I../lib/tdb/include -I../lib/ntdb 
-DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I/~/opt/buildroot-gcc342/include -Iinclude/autoconf -Iautoconf 
-Iautoconf/source3 -Iinclude -I./include -I. -I. -I./../lib/replace -I./../lib/tevent -I../lib/ccan/.. 
-I./librpc -I./.. -I./../lib/tdb_compat -I./../lib/popt -DLDAP_DEPRECATED  
-I/home/constantine/software_forge/2013/5_month/samba/samba-4.0.5/source3/lib -I.. 
-I./../lib/ldb/include -D_SAMBA_BUILD_=3 -D_SAMBA_BUILD_=3 -fPIE -c lib/sysquotas_4A.c -o lib/sysquotas_4A.o
```

I run

> ./configure --target=mips-linux-uclibc --host=i686

And before that I run these:

```
export LD_LIBARY_PATH=~/opt/buildroot-gcc342/lib
export LDFLAGS=-L/~/opt/buildroot-gcc342/lib
export CPPFLAGS=-I/~/opt/buildroot-gcc342/include
export CC=~/opt/buildroot-gcc342/bin/mipsel-linux-uclib-gcc
```

Also, I've installed quota package, removed -w flag (as friends from OS/X suggested) and yet it's still the same. It does compile for native architecture. Also I've looked to the sources and I saw these

```
#if _LINUX_QUOTA_VERSION < 2
struct dqblk{
   ...
   u_int32_t dqb_curblocks;
   ...
}
#else
#define QIF_BLIMITS     1
#define QIF_SPACE       2
...
struct dqblk{
   ...
}
#endif
```

and checked the includes, and it should be working.
I am new to linux and cross compiling, so I'm terribly sorry if this question is stupid. Yet somehow Google search results can't help me so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I've found a solution and I'll leave the answer if someone encounters similar situation.

The above steps are completely correct. Yet the one should make sure that the headers are taken from the MIPS compiler directory. So I changed the source code of  **sysquotas_4A.c**  by specifying the full path to the  **quota.h**  which in my case is  **/opt/buildroot-gcc342/include/sys/quota.h**  and it works just fine.

Cheers,
Constantine